# Maximum allowed file size for upload is 2m?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, upload

I get this error:

> "Maximum allowed file size for upload is 2m. Please check your server PHP settings"

Magento ver 1.9.1.0
VPS Linux server with WHM Manager and cPanel access.

Every time I try to upload a file larger then 2M inside Magento it gives me that error.
I have added the line **php_value upload_max_filesize 10M** to both my **.htaccess** and **php.ini** files in the **public_html** folder.

I have gone into WHM and into the configuration editor and changed it to 10mb there. I hop into cPanel and in the PHP Configuration it says its set to 10m, but, when I go to **sewchacha.com/phpinfo.php** it says that the max upload size is set to 2M.

I have multiple other sites on this server in their own cPanel's and they show the correct 10m with the phpinfo.php file. It is only this site that doesn't show it correctly. Yes I have restarted the server several times after making the changes in the .ini and .htaccess files.

Is there something in Magento that is overriding the server settings?

Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is APC in play?

Comment: Have you put a `phpinfo()` file at the root and checked what the actual value is set to? Some hosts ignore `php.ini` and `htaccess` overrides.

Comment: Yes, I have the phpinfo.php file in the root right now, and it shows 2mb for the upload_max_filesize when the server shows it set to 10 in both the WHM and cPanel, and the .htaccess file and php.ini files both have it set to 10M in them.

Comment: @Melvyn what it the "APC"?

Comment: @Melvyn (I Figured out what APC was) I do not see APC enabled when I go to the phpinfo.php. I don't see it enabled on my other site either. My other site works fine and shows the correct upload size in its phpinfo.php file.

Comment: And [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)?

Comment: unbelievable, LOL, after spending hours on this I checked for the 20th time and the stupid php.ini file had "upload_max_filesize 10M" and not "upload_max_filesize = 10M" LOL that was the problem, it works now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer? And accept it when it lets you? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Disclaimer : On behalf of the OP, turns his comment into an answer

After spending hours on this I checked for the 20th time and the stupid `php.ini` file had `upload_max_filesize 10M` and not `upload_max_filesize = 10M` .

LOL that was the problem, it works now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

See your PHP Info - create a file called e.g. **info.php** and add following PHP code to this file:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

Run this file on your server and you will see all PHP settings, see **upload_max_filesize** directive.[image: php info]

If there is only 2M (2 MB), you should increase your upload file size in your **php.ini**.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Save your php.ini and restart your server.

---

**Is it not your server? (Just to test)**

Try to add the following code to your **index.php** file (or your main script file):

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

[Reference here.](http://www.phoca.cz/documents/38-tools/172-how-to-upload-files-larger-than-2-mb)

Comment: Adding that on my index.php is also not working.

Comment: @AfreenSheikh add in your pub/index.php

Comment: Adding it in my pub/index.php also didn't work.